# How to upload image to php server from Android App?

Tags: php, android, server

I am developing an android app.
I want to upload an image to php server.
The problem is that, the image on server side which gets uploaded is blank.

My android app code is:

```
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

    byte[] byteArray;
    byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    String ConvertImage;
    ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

ConvertImage is sent to server using GET Query "url?image=ConvertImage"

On Server Side, php script is:

```
    $image = $_GET['image'];

    $img = base64_decode($image);
    $path = "Images/new1.png";

    file_put_contents($path, $img);
```

After running the php script, the file gets created but i do not see the image.

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump `$_GET['image']`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using smaller Images, if it gets uploaded than the problem is with the image size.
Also I would suggest you to post images using Multipart method rather than converting them to string and passing in url. Of course only if you have access to the server.